# I am trying to replicate this MySQL trigger in T-SQL, but it's returning a null value

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

MySQL below

```
# BEFORE INSERT
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER before_salaries_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON salaries
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.salary < 0 THEN 
        SET NEW.salary = 0; 
    END IF; 
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

T-SQL below:

```
ALTER TRIGGER before_salaries_insert 
ON employees
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Code decimal(10,2);

    SELECT @code = e.salary
    FROM employees AS e
    JOIN inserted AS i ON e.salary = i.salary; 

    IF @Code < 0 
    BEGIN 
        SET @Code = 0
    END;
    
    INSERT INTO employees (first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, hire_date, job_id, salary, manager_id, department_id)
        SELECT
            i.first_name, i.last_name, i.email, i.phone_number, 
            i.hire_date, i.job_id, @Code, i.manager_id, i.department_id
        FROM
            inserted i
END;
```

I'm new to T-SQL and SQL Server. I'm doing this only for learning purposes and to brush up on my skills. The trigger is essential saying set salary to 0 when given salary is below 0.

Comment: One **very important** thing is that in Oracle you have `FOR EACH ROW`. That does not exist in SQL Server, and your virtual tables `deleted` and `inserted` will contain **all the  rows**, not just one.

Comment: That's not the trigger format of Oracle what you wrote titled **PLSQL below**

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan It's MySQL. Isn't that Oracle?

Comment: PLSQL suggests and reminds Oracle, doesn't that ?

Comment: Aside: In SQL Server you could use a [check constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#Check) to prevent negative salaries. Note that your trigger doesn't enforce the rule for `update` statements whereas a check constraint is always active.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I have updated my question thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Below seems to work

```
ALTER TRIGGER before_salaries_insert
ON employees
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO employees(first_name,last_name,email,phone_number,hire_date,job_id,salary,manager_id,department_id)
Select i.first_name, i.last_name, i.email, i.phone_number, i.hire_date,i.job_id,
case
    when i.salary < 0 then 0
    else i.salary
end as salarycheck,
i.manager_id,i.department_id
from inserted i
END
```

Comment: Yes, but why does it work? Don't get me wrong, I'm glad you found an answer to your question, and it's even better that you've posted the solution as a self answer - but as a rule of thumb, code only answers are considered low quality - because they don't explain anything. Future readers will benefit much more from an answer that explains why and how it works (to an extent, of course) than from an answer that contains only code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have the solution in this reddit thread https://www.reddit.com/r/SQL/comments/jhome7/i_am_trying_to_replicate_this_plsql_trigger_in/